# Rails Internalization - Included the Google Maps API multiple times error

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, google-maps

I have looked through other stackoverflow question regarding this error but I can't find any post similar to my situation as well as got the solution work in my scenario.

I am using Rails Internationalization (I18n)'s Localized Views

- Have two view page called `index/ch.html.haml` and `index/en.html.haml`
- Have two `<a>` (`root_url/ch` and `root_url/en`) on the nav bar which leads to each of the page
- Both view page have google map div
- I include the script (`%script{src: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=*my_key&callback=initMap"}`
  ) in the `application.html.haml`

This is my `application.html.haml` page.

```
!!!
%html
  %head
    %meta{:content => "text/html; charset=UTF-8", "http-equiv" => "Content-Type"}/
    %meta{:content => "width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no", :name => "viewport"}/
    %meta{:charset => "utf-8"}/
    %title MyApps
    = stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true
    = javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true
    = csrf_meta_tags
  %body
    = yield
    %script{src: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=*my_key-6w&callback=initMap"}
```

When I **first load the page**, there are **no errors**. But when I go to the other page (i.e. `ch` to `en`), then I get this error in the console `You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors.`. The more times I change from one page to another, the more errors I got.

NOTE: I can't find any other places in the apps that load the googleapi script. Also, when I remove the script, I can't load the map anymore. So I guess my problem is mainly due to the fact that the page is rendered without being refreshed. (When I refresh the page, the error has gone)

Appreciate if anyone can give me some suggestion to solve this. Thanks.

Comment: Can you try moving your `script` right above the `csrf_meta_tags` ?

Comment: Maybe because you put your script inside the yield (which will be put to all of the pages).

Comment: I tried moved the `script` before `csrf_meta_tags` but then this caused the script to be loaded only once. Therefore, after I switch to the other page, then I can't view the maps anymore unless I refresh.

Comment: Usually, when you you have the need to refresh a page, it's because of turbolinks. Try removing turbolinks from `application.js` and from `application.html.erb` and see if it fixes the issue.

Comment: @jeramaedybohol, it is working!! Thanks for the solution! :D
The reason of why my script is not working is because turbolink does not `reload the JavaScript and CSS between each page change`, but `keep the current instance alive and replace only the body and the title in the head`,  therefore sending multiple times Google Maps API. The tradeoff of this solution is my apps will work slower but it is OK for me.

Comment: Well, for turbolinks, I placed my script tag of googlemaps in head section, even after the csrf_meta_tags and i have done my bindings etc on google map in "turbolinks:load" event listener which is called on every new page load by turbolinks. So it is working everywhere in my app and error is gone too without slowing the app. Cheers!